# Multiple drag & drop and upload files store in the selected folder

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I have created a drag and drop upload file in the selected folder. I have a problem saving multiple files in the selected folder.

Now my working result can drag and drop 1 file to save in the selected folder, but multiple select files cannot work and cannot upload files at the same time. This is my working frontend in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qh7ge8cn/

My backend save file to the selected folder code:

```html
<?php  
$target_path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/drag_drop/";  
$target_path = $target_path.basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);   
  echo $target_path; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {  
    echo "File uploaded successfully!";  
} else{  
    echo "Sorry, file not uploaded, please try again!";  
}  
?>
```

Below is my result:

[image: Output1]

Actually, I want the result can drag multiple files at the same time upload in the selected folder when I have clicked the `Upload File` button, like the below picture:

[image: output2]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requested BY OP, example source code as  following:

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Multiple File Upload using Ajax, Jquery and PHP</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        
function vpb_multiple_file_uploader(vpb_configuration_settings)
{
    this.vpb_settings = vpb_configuration_settings;
    this.vpb_files = "";
    this.vpb_browsed_files = []
    var self = this;
    var vpb_msg = "Sorry, your browser does not support this application. Thank You!";
    
    //Get all browsed file extensions
    function vpb_file_ext(file) {
        return (/[.]/.exec(file)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(file.toLowerCase()) : '';
    }
    
    /* Display added files which are ready for upload */
    //with their file types, names, size, date last modified along with an option to remove an unwanted file
    vpb_multiple_file_uploader.prototype.vpb_show_added_files = function(vpb_value)
    {
        this.vpb_files = vpb_value;
        if(this.vpb_files.length > 0)
        {
            var vpb_added_files_displayer = vpb_file_id = "";
            for(var i = 0; i<this.vpb_files.length; i++)
            {
                //Use the names of the files without their extensions as their ids
                var files_name_without_extensions = this.vpb_files[i].name.substr(0, this.vpb_files[i].name.lastIndexOf('.')) || this.vpb_files[i].name;
                vpb_file_id = files_name_without_extensions.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
                
                var vpb_file_to_add = vpb_file_ext(this.vpb_files[i].name);
                var vpb_class = $("#added_class").val();
                var vpb_file_icon;
                
                //Check and display File Size
                var vpb_fileSize = (this.vpb_files[i].size / 1024);
                if (vpb_fileSize / 1024 > 1)
                {
                    if (((vpb_fileSize / 1024) / 1024) > 1)
                    {
                        vpb_fileSize = (Math.round(((vpb_fileSize / 1024) / 1024) * 100) / 100);
                        var vpb_actual_fileSize = vpb_fileSize + " GB";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vpb_fileSize = (Math.round((vpb_fileSize / 1024) * 100) / 100)
                        var vpb_actual_fileSize = vpb_fileSize + " MB";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    vpb_fileSize = (Math.round(vpb_fileSize * 100) / 100)
                    var vpb_actual_fileSize = vpb_fileSize  + " KB";
                }
                
                //Check and display the date that files were last modified
                var vpb_date_last_modified = new Date(this.vpb_files[i].lastModifiedDate);
                var dd = vpb_date_last_modified.getDate();
                var mm = vpb_date_last_modified.getMonth() + 1;
                var yyyy = vpb_date_last_modified.getFullYear();
                var vpb_date_last_modified_file = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
                
                //File Display Classes
                if( vpb_class == 'vpb_blue' ) { 
                    var new_classc = 'vpb_white';
                } else {
                    var new_classc = 'vpb_blue';
                }
                
                
                if(typeof this.vpb_files[i] != undefined && this.vpb_files[i].name != "")
                {
                    //Check for the type of file browsed so as to represent each file with the appropriate file icon
                    
                    if( vpb_file_to_add == "jpg" || vpb_file_to_add == "JPG" || vpb_file_to_add == "jpeg" || vpb_file_to_add == "JPEG" || vpb_file_to_add == "gif" || vpb_file_to_add == "GIF" || vpb_file_to_add == "png" || vpb_file_to_add == "PNG" ) 
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/images_file.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "doc" || vpb_file_to_add == "docx" || vpb_file_to_add == "rtf" || vpb_file_to_add == "DOC" || vpb_file_to_add == "DOCX" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/doc.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "pdf" || vpb_file_to_add == "PDF" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/pdf.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "txt" || vpb_file_to_add == "TXT" || vpb_file_to_add == "RTF" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/txt.png" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "php" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/php.png" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "css" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/general.png" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "js" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/general.png" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "html" || vpb_file_to_add == "HTML" || vpb_file_to_add == "htm" || vpb_file_to_add == "HTM" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/html.png" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "setup" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/setup.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "video" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/video.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "real" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/real.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "psd" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/psd.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "fla" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/fla.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "xls" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/xls.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "swf" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/swf.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "eps" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/eps.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "exe" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/exe.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "binary" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/binary.png" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else if( vpb_file_to_add == "zip" )
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/archive.png" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vpb_file_icon = '<img src="images/general.png" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="" />';
                    }
                    
                    //Assign browsed files to a variable so as to later display them below
                    vpb_added_files_displayer += '<tr id="add_fileID'+vpb_file_id+'" class="'+new_classc+'"><td>'+vpb_file_icon+' '+this.vpb_files[i].name.substring(0, 40)+'</td><td><span id="uploading_'+vpb_file_id+'"><span style=color:blue;>Ready</span></span></td><td>'+vpb_actual_fileSize+'</td><td><span id="remove'+vpb_file_id+'"><span class="vpb_files_remove_left_inner" onclick="vpb_remove_this_file(\''+vpb_file_id+'\',\''+this.vpb_files[i].name+'\');">Remove</span></span></td></tr></div>';
                    
                }
            }
            //Display browsed files on the screen to the user who wants to upload them
            $("#add_files").append(vpb_added_files_displayer);
            $("#added_class").val(new_classc);
        }
    }
    
    //File Reader
    vpb_multiple_file_uploader.prototype.vpb_read_file = function(vpb_e) {
        if(vpb_e.target.files) {
            self.vpb_show_added_files(vpb_e.target.files);
            self.vpb_browsed_files.push(vpb_e.target.files);
        } else {
            alert('Sorry, a file you have specified could not be read at the moment. Thank You!');
        }
    }
    
    
    function addEvent(type, el, fn){
    if (window.addEventListener){
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent){
        var f = function(){
          fn.call(el, window.event);
        };          
        el.attachEvent('on' + type, f)
    }
}

    
    //Get the ids of all added files and also start the upload when called
    vpb_multiple_file_uploader.prototype.vpb_starter = function() {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {       
             var vpb_browsed_file_ids = $("#"+this.vpb_settings.vpb_form_id).find("input[type='file']").eq(0).attr("id");
             document.getElementById(vpb_browsed_file_ids).addEventListener("change", this.vpb_read_file, false);
             document.getElementById(this.vpb_settings.vpb_form_id).addEventListener("submit", this.vpb_submit_added_files, true);
        } 
        else { alert(vpb_msg); }
    }
    
    //Call the uploading function when click on the upload button
    vpb_multiple_file_uploader.prototype.vpb_submit_added_files = function(){ self.vpb_upload_bgin(); }
    
    //Start uploads
    vpb_multiple_file_uploader.prototype.vpb_upload_bgin = function() {
        if(this.vpb_browsed_files.length > 0) {
            for(var k=0; k<this.vpb_browsed_files.length; k++){
                var file = this.vpb_browsed_files[k];
                this.vasPLUS(file,0);
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Main file uploader
    vpb_multiple_file_uploader.prototype.vasPLUS = function(file,file_counter)
    {
        if(typeof file[file_counter] != undefined && file[file_counter] != '')
        {
            //Use the file names without their extensions as their ids
            var files_name_without_extensions = file[file_counter].name.substr(0, file[file_counter].name.lastIndexOf('.')) || file[file_counter].name;
            var ids = files_name_without_extensions.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
            var vpb_browsed_file_ids = $("#"+this.vpb_settings.vpb_form_id).find("input[type='file']").eq(0).attr("id");
            
            var removed_file = $("#"+ids).val();
            
            if ( removed_file != "" && removed_file != undefined && removed_file == ids )
            {
                self.vasPLUS(file,file_counter+1);
            }
            else
            {
                var dataString = new FormData();
                dataString.append('upload_file',file[file_counter]);
                dataString.append('upload_file_ids',ids);
                    
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:this.vpb_settings.vpb_server_url,
                    data:dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function() 
                    {
                        $("#uploading_"+ids).html('<div align="left"><img src="images/loadings.gif" width="80" align="absmiddle" title="Upload...."/></div>');
                        $("#remove"+ids).html('<div align="center" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:blue;">Uploading...</div>');
                    },
                    success:function(response) 
                    {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var response_brought = response.indexOf(ids);
                            if ( response_brought != -1) {
                                $("#uploading_"+ids).html('<div align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:blue;">Completed</div>');
                                $("#remove"+ids).html('<div align="center" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:gray;">Uploaded</div>');
                            } else {
                                var fileType_response_brought = response.indexOf('file_type_error');
                                if ( fileType_response_brought != -1) {
                                    
                                    var filenamewithoutextension = response.replace('file_type_error&', '').substr(0, response.replace('file_type_error&', '').lastIndexOf('.')) || response.replace('file_type_error&', '');
                                    var fileID = filenamewithoutextension.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
                                    $("#uploading_"+fileID).html('<div align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:red;">Invalid File</div>');
                                    $("#remove"+fileID).html('<div align="center" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:orange;">Cancelled</div>');
                                    
                                } else {
                                    var filesize_response_brought = response.indexOf('file_size_error');
                                    if ( filesize_response_brought != -1) {
                                        var filenamewithoutextensions = response.replace('file_size_error&', '').substr(0, response.replace('file_size_error&', '').lastIndexOf('.')) || response.replace('file_size_error&', '');
                                        var fileID = filenamewithoutextensions.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
                                        $("#uploading_"+fileID).html('<div align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:red;">Exceeded Size</div>');
                                        $("#remove"+fileID).html('<div align="center" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:orange;">Cancelled</div>');
                                    } else {
                                        var general_response_brought = response.indexOf('general_system_error');
                                        if ( general_response_brought != -1) {
                                            alert('Sorry, the file was not uploaded...');
                                        }
                                        else { /* Do nothing */}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (file_counter+1 < file.length ) {
                                self.vasPLUS(file,file_counter+1); 
                            } 
                            else {}
                        },2000);
                    }
                });
             }
        } 
        else { alert('Sorry, this system could not verify the identity of the file you were trying to upload at the moment. Thank You!'); }
    }
    this.vpb_starter();
}

function vpb_remove_this_file(id, filename)
{
    if(confirm('If you are sure to remove the file: '+filename+' then click on OK otherwise, Cancel it.'))
    {
        $("#vpb_removed_files").append('<input type="hidden" id="'+id+'" value="'+id+'">');
        $("#add_fileID"+id).slideUp();
    }
    return false;
}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Call the main function
    new vpb_multiple_file_uploader
    ({
        vpb_form_id: "form_id", // Form ID
        autoSubmit: true,
        vpb_server_url: "upload.php" 
    });
});
</script>
<style>
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
}
span{
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
<body>

<center>

<h2 style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Multiple Files Upload</h2>

<form name="form_id" id="form_id" action="javascript:void(0);" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:800px; margin-top:20px;">  
    <input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files" id="vasplus_multiple_files" multiple="multiple" style="padding:5px;"/>      
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" style="padding:5px;"/>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:60%;" id="add_files">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Name</th>
            <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
            <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
            <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    </tbody>
</table>

</center>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Make another file called upload.php:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $vpb_file_name = strip_tags($_FILES['upload_file']['name']); //File Name
    $vpb_file_id = strip_tags($_POST['upload_file_ids']); // File id is gotten from the file name
    $vpb_file_size = $_FILES['upload_file']['size']; // File Size
    $vpb_uploaded_files_location = 'uploads/'; //This is the directory where uploaded files are saved on your server
    $vpb_final_location = $vpb_uploaded_files_location . $vpb_file_name; //Directory to save file plus the file to be saved
    //Without Validation and does not save filenames in the database
    if(move_uploaded_file(strip_tags($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']), $vpb_final_location))
    {
        //Display the file id
        echo $vpb_file_id;
    }
    else
    {
        //Display general system error
        echo 'general_system_error';
    }

}
?>
```

Create an empty folder called uploads. Make sure you ad your dependencies like jquery.js and such, the required dependencies are on the header which will return a 404 as I've not included cdn.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The back-end I use your method cannot save to the selected folder.

Comment: Well yes, the backend wouldn't work because I didn't use your backend code, I gave an example code. You cannot just simply paste a code and expect to to work. I've updated the backend code in the answer, try it now.

Comment: Ok. I have tried it, but my folder no response to show what I uploaded files. Is front end problem? I have added name="fileToUpload" in the input but also cannot work.

Comment: Could you please update your question to include your front end code (HTML and Javascript) and your PHP code so that I may have a proper look at it?

Comment: This edited frontend https://jsfiddle.net/oj4L8re6/

Comment: Yes i'm aware of the edited jsfiddle, the thing is, the javascript in the fiddle uses ajax. If the url in in the ajax is just "ajax.php", you may want to check if the ajax is even working or if your php file is even called ajax.php. The url may also be wrong. Check your inspect element for the javascript error.

Comment: Yes. Is stucked for me. Do you have any sample source code let me try?

Comment: I've updated my asnwer. Remember to include your dependencies like bootstrap , jquery and such.

Comment: Terima kasih. Thanks to take the time to help me solve this problem.

Comment: 1 more question on design, how to change the design in the "choose file button" same as my question result?

Comment: Because I want to use back my design got word 'Drop file here or click to upload'

Comment: You can put your code in the form as long as you have the id="form_id" action="javascript:void(0);" or just change your code's input to initiate the javascript action when the is file being uploaded. Since your problem is solved, I'd suggest you create another question with javascript/html/css tags if you still find yourself having trouble.

Comment: I have another problem based on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65626849/upload-multiple-files-cannot-append-the-files-data-and-upload-into-selected-fold 
If you have free time can help me to check. Thanks.